# Search to see if text exists in a column, if it does then count the row

Tags: excel, formula

I have 2 worksheets in Excel:

**Plot**

```
plot    region  jobCount    
1       MK      #VALUE! 
2       MK      #VALUE! 
3       MK      #VALUE!
4       MK      #VALUE! 
5       MK      #VALUE!
6       MK      #VALUE! 
7       MK      #VALUE!
8       MK      #VALUE!
9       MK      #VALUE!
10      MK      #VALUE!
```

**Waypoint**

[image]

How would I search column D in the **Waypoint** table to count where the `plot+region` (i.e. MK1, MK2...) matches the postcode and where the sequence is equal to 1.

This is the formula I have so far:

```
=SEARCH(CONCATENATE(B:B,"",A:A),Waypoint!D:D,"0")
```

but it keeps returning #VALUE in the **Plot** table.

I want it to concatenate whatever is in plot and region, then check column D in **Waypoint** to see if there are any matches, if there is a match is the value in sequence = 1, if so then count it... (sorry if this pseudocode is not clear enough)

e.g. in the example above

- For plot 1, there are 2 matches so jobCount = 2
- For plot 2, there is 1 match so jobCount = 1
- For plot 4, there are 1 matches so jobCount = 1

I hope it makes sense, I've tried very hard to be clear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the region/plot combination in coumn D is always followed by a space character, use this in the Plot sheet in cell C2 and copy down:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B2&A2&" ",Waypoint!$D$1:$D$1000))),--(Waypoint!$C$1:$C$1000=1))
```

You don't want to use this with whole columns, since it will become slow. If the number of rows is variable, use a dynamic range.